# Find all words in file with specific offset in each line (bash)

Tags: linux, bash

Can I find and save in array (or string) all words in file that starts from specific offset in each line?

For example, I have file with the following text:

```
  270  mc
  271  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/unstable
  272  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install go-mtpfs
  273  sudo apt-get install go-mtpfs-unity
  274  go-mtpf
```

I want to get the following list from it:

```
mc sudo sudo sudo go-mtfp
```

Comment: Are you looking for the second word in the line?  Or for a word that starts at the 5th character? i.e. how should the program respond to input of `1 34 foo bar`?

Comment: This looks like the output of the `history` shell command, so he likely wants the second word on each line. And *not* a particular character-offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting 2nd field:

```
cut -d " " -f2 file
```

Or getting values at a fixed offset (starting at position 5)

```
cut -c5- file
```

Comment: Both these commands assume there is exactly one space between the first column and the second. That's consistent with what the user asked for, but it's a typical beginner's trap when using `cut -d<c> -f<n>`; people tend to assume it merges adjacent delimiters which it doesn't.

Comment: Oh, and it also assumes that there are no space in front of the first column. :)

Comment: No it doesn't assume that.  If you're using first cut command then you just need to change field number as per the position of the data.

Answer (score 1):

try this line:

```
awk '$0=$2' file
```